# Oneiric's init (upstart) taking up 99% cpu on openvz

Tags: openvz, upstart, init, cpu-usage, ubuntu-11.10

I'm having a problem with a openvz vps which came with Ubuntu Natty (11.04) and I recently upgraded to Oneiric (11.10). After a reboot I found the init process stuck at ~99% cpu and the loadavg floating around 1.0. I've read about past issues with upstart on openvz but it looks like they should have been solved by now.

I upgraded by switching the repos and running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Did I do anything wrong? Any ideas how to solve this? If you need more info I'll provide them.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this fix: https://code.launchpad.net/~jammy/+archive/upstart.fix-880049

Below steps fixed my problem in Ubuntu 11.10 today.

Add this PPA to your system:

add-apt-repository ppa:jammy/upstart.fix-880049

Update your system:
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1):

init needs access to /dev/console, which does not exist by default within the vm.

You might be able to fix it by executing `vzctl set 105 --devices c:5:1:rw --save` outside the vm - for linux-vserver a simple `mknod /var/lib/vservers/servername/dev/console c 5 1` is sufficient.

Credits for the openvz command, and background info: [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68144/init-process-at-100-cpu-usage)